# Disable webpack reloading

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am configuring simple webpack stack and it works, but the thing is that it makes app reloading on each file change. Is there any way to turn off reloading upon each file change? I want to manually reload page, I am also not using hot reload and I don't want to use it.

For server I am using file:

```
/*eslint no-console:0 */
'use strict';
require('core-js/fn/object/assign');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server');
const config = require('./webpack.config');
const open = require('open');

new WebpackDevServer(webpack(config), config.devServer)
.listen(config.port, 'localhost', (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  console.log('Listening at localhost:' + config.port);
  console.log('Opening your system browser...');
  open('http://localhost:' + config.port + '/webpack-dev-server/');
});
```

And for webpack configuration these are some parts:

```
module.exports = {
  additionalPaths: additionalPaths,
  port: defaultSettings.port,
  debug: true,
  devtool: 'eval',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/../dist'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: defaultSettings.publicPath
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './src/',
    historyApiFallback: true,
    hot: false,
    port: defaultSettings.port,
    publicPath: defaultSettings.publicPath,
    noInfo: false
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
    alias: {
      plugins: `${defaultSettings.srcPath}/../plugins`,
      core: `${defaultSettings.srcPath}/../core`
    }
  }
};
```

and dev config:

```
let config = Object.assign({}, baseConfig, {
  entry: {
    start: ['./src/index'],
    vendors: [],
    core: './plugins/lunchbadger-core/index',
    plugins: infoFile.plugins.map((plugin) => { return ('./plugins/lunchbadger-' + plugin); })
  },
  cache: true,
  devtool: 'eval',
  plugins: [
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ],
  module: defaultSettings.getDefaultModules()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the solution is to skip webpack-dev-server in this case and run webpack in watch mode (`webpack --watch`) instead? The watch mode will recompile your files as it detects changes.

In this case yu would have to serve your site separately (say using [serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve)) but this combination would achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of an old question, but right now `webpack-dev-server --liveReload false` could help in this case I believe.

Comment: There is also the option inside `angular.json` too, precisely `architect > serve > options > liveReload`